# Inconsistency in behaviour for comment upvote/flag and delete between mobile and desktop browser

Tags: feature-request, comments, design, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

On my mobile Chrome browser all the items (flag/upvote and delete) for comments are always visible due to the lack of pointer item like a mouse. This is fine.

But on desktop browser "delete" link is visible only when mouse pointer is over the comment:

> [image: comment delete]

In the same time upvote/flag items are always visible despite of the mouse overness:

> [image: flag/upvote]

I suggest to make behaviour consistent, either:

- show the all items always like for mobile browser, or
- show the item only when mouse pointer is over it (preferred for me, and it seems so worked before)

Comment: FYI the change to make the vote and flag buttons always visible was not to optimize for touchscreens; it was to show new users that they are able to flag comments.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog what about old users?